# Hadoop MapReduce - Euler's Totient / Sum of Totient (and other Mathematical operation)

Tags: java, hadoop, cluster-computing

As part of my studies I am working on an implementation of a Sum of Totient (Euler's Totient) with different parallel computing languages, and I am quite struggling with the MapReduce one to be honest. 
The main goal is to do kind of a benchmark with the runtime, efficiency and so on ...

My code is running right now, and I got the right output, but it's pretty slow, and I am wondering why.

Is it because of my implementation or is it because Hadoop MadReduce isn't made for this purpose.
I also implemented a combiner because from what I read it was supposed to optimize the code, but it's not.
Sorry if the question seems stupid but I didn't find anything on internet and I am tired of trying everything without any result.

My input file is a range of value from 1 to 15000

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 14998 14999 15000
```

And I am working on a cluster of 32 nodes, my goal was to have each node doing the calculation of a portion of my range (combiner), and then summing all the "sub sums" of the combiner in the reducer.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class NewTotient {

  public static long hcf(long x, long y)
  {
    long t;

    while (y != 0) {
      t = x % y;
      x = y;
      y = t;
    }
    return x;
  }

  public static boolean relprime(long x, long y)
  {
    return hcf(x, y) == 1;
  }

  public static long euler(long n)
  {
    long length, i;

    length = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
      if (relprime(n, i))
        length++;
    return length;
  }

  public static class TotientMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (String val : value.toString().split(" ")) {
            context.write(new Text(), new IntWritable(Integer.valueOf(val)));
        }
    }
  }

  public static class TotientCombiner extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    //private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int sum = 0;
          for (IntWritable val : values) {
              sum += NewTotient.euler(val.get());
          }
      }
  }

  public static class TotientReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    //private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int sum = 1;
          for (IntWritable val : values) {
              sum += val.get();
          }
          context.write(null, new IntWritable(sum));
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    System.out.println("\n\n__________________________________________________________\n"+"Starting Job\n"+"__________________________________________________________\n\n");
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Sum of Totient");
    job.setJarByClass(NewTotient.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TotientMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(TotientCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(TotientReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    //job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    //job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    final double duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000.0;
    System.out.println("\n\n__________________________________________________________\n"+"Job Finished in " + duration + " seconds\n"+"__________________________________________________________\n\n");
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

And if it can help here is my output for a Dataset going from 0 to 10 (so basically I am just calculating the sum of the 10 first Totient :

```
__________________________________________________________
Starting Job
__________________________________________________________


2018-04-02 06:09:27,583 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at bwlf32/137.195.143.132:33312
2018-04-02 06:09:28,377 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2018-04-02 06:09:28,423 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/jo20/.staging/job_1522471222360_0016
2018-04-02 06:09:28,775 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2018-04-02 06:09:29,029 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2018-04-02 06:09:29,101 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2018-04-02 06:09:29,288 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1522471222360_0016
2018-04-02 06:09:29,290 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2018-04-02 06:09:29,538 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2018-04-02 06:09:29,539 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2018-04-02 06:09:29,628 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1522471222360_0016
2018-04-02 06:09:29,687 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://bwlf32:33314/proxy/application_1522471222360_0016/
2018-04-02 06:09:29,688 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1522471222360_0016
2018-04-02 06:09:37,849 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1522471222360_0016 running in uber mode : false
2018-04-02 06:09:37,852 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2018-04-02 06:09:44,960 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2018-04-02 06:09:52,008 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
2018-04-02 06:09:52,022 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1522471222360_0016 completed successfully
2018-04-02 06:09:52,178 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 53
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=6
        FILE: Number of bytes written=414497
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=123
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=8
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters
        Launched map tasks=1
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=9126
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=9688
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4563
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=4844
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4563
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=4844
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1168128
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=1240064
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=1
        Map output records=10
        Map output bytes=50
        Map output materialized bytes=6
        Input split bytes=102
        Combine input records=10
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=0
        Reduce shuffle bytes=6
        Reduce input records=0
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=0
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=157
        CPU time spent (ms)=2220
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=507772928
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3889602560
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=347078656
        Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=306073600
        Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=1945808896
        Peak Reduce Physical memory (bytes)=201699328
        Peak Reduce Virtual memory (bytes)=1943793664
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters
        Bytes Read=21
    File Output Format Counters
        Bytes Written=0


__________________________________________________________
Job Finished in 26.225 seconds
__________________________________________________________


2018-04-02 06:09:52,182 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1522471222360_0016
2018-04-02 06:09:52,188 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1522471222360_0016 running in uber mode : false
2018-04-02 06:09:52,188 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
2018-04-02 06:09:52,193 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1522471222360_0016 completed successfully
2018-04-02 06:09:52,201 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 53
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=6
        FILE: Number of bytes written=414497
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=123
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=8
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters
        Launched map tasks=1
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=9126
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=9688
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4563
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=4844
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4563
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=4844
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1168128
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=1240064
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=1
        Map output records=10
        Map output bytes=50
        Map output materialized bytes=6
        Input split bytes=102
        Combine input records=10
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=0
        Reduce shuffle bytes=6
        Reduce input records=0
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=0
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=157
        CPU time spent (ms)=2220
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=507772928
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3889602560
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=347078656
        Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=306073600
        Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=1945808896
        Peak Reduce Physical memory (bytes)=201699328
        Peak Reduce Virtual memory (bytes)=1943793664
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters
        Bytes Read=21
    File Output Format Counters
        Bytes Written=0
```

And using my sequential code in java it's way faster :

```
real    0m0.512s
user    0m0.279s
sys     0m0.142s
```

Just to be clear, I have to use this way of calculation, because it's slow enough to have interesting comparison between different system, and I can't improve the speed of my system using a smarter way of calculation even if I know there are the idea of counting all prime factors and their multiples and subtract this count from n to get the totient function value (Prime factors and multiples of prime factors won’t have gcd as 1).

Answer (score 2):

Here you are providing the input from a file in a single line . The key used in your mapper is new line , so since there is only one line , it will be processed by a single map task, hence it wont be processing inputs in parallel.
One thing you can do , is to provide each input number in new line instead of space and change the mapper accordingly.
Also combiner wont make much sense here , since you are not using different keys in the map output

Comment: I am bit confused on how the mapper should change.

Comment: I may have misunderstood something, but where am I saying that I am using a new line ?
Usually, I am processing by new line using the line.* no ?

Comment: The default input format for file input will be TextInputFormat  , it treats each line number ( offset ) in the file as the key and the whole line as the value and the RecordReader will read each line in the file and pass the key and value to the mapper. refer to below link which describes how the mapreduce program works .                                            https://mapr.com/blog/how-write-mapreduce-program/